# continuous random variable expectation and variance

Tags: probability, continuity

you have a continuous random variable X uniformly distributed, and E(X) = 3, calculate the V(X)

am stuck, how am i supposed to get the variance with no function in the first place

Comment: There is not enough information to answer this.

Comment: https://www.google.fr/search?q=variance+from+expected+value

Comment: Just to elaborate:  Suppose $X_1$ is identically $3$ (or, if you feel that's not continuous, make it uniform on some extremely small interval $[3-\epsilon, 3+\epsilon]$)  What is $Var(X_1)$?  Now let $X_2$ be uniform on $[1,5]$ and compute $Var(X_2)$.

Comment: what information do u need to answer that question, because as far as am concerned, this is the exact way the question was written, i had another one which was a little different, cause it was a discrete case which was, that u had a discrete random variable with E(X)=5 and he wanted u to find the values of the distribution, given that its a uniform distribution which means the probability for each value of x is equal and the answer was [-1,11] which means X takes all values from -1 to 11 which are 13 values, then that means the probablity for each on is 1/13 if u do the math it equals to 5

Comment: lulu, i dont get what you are saying, forgive me but am truly bad at this and am having a hard time understanding please bear with me

Comment: If you want a comment to reach a particular user you need to include "@", as in @mathew .   I gave you two examples of continuous, uniform variables each with expectation $3$ but with different variance.  Hence the variance is not determined by the information you provided.

Comment: @lulu sorry, am new here and didnt know u can mention people here aswell, anyways yeah i thought of that too, knowing that the information to get the answer is not enough just wanted to make sure that there was no method to get it calculated, only thing i thought of was getting to equations with 2 unknowns and calculating them together, still havent figured out how to do that though

Comment: It's simply not determined.  If, say, you knew $E[X^2]$ you could do it, as $Var[X]=E[X^2]-E[X]^2$.    But just think about it...if all the data is concentrated near the mean, the variance is near $0$.  If, on the other hand, all the data is far from the mean the variance is high.  These observations have nothing to do with the location of the mean!

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ is uniformly distributed on some interval $[a,b]$, with $\mathbb{E}[X]=3$ we know that $3=(b-a)/2$. From this we can deduce that this is a interval symmetric around $3$ and thus we have that the interval is from the form: $[3-d,3+d]$, for some real number $d>0$.

Also we know that the formula for the variance is $(b-a)^2/12$. Filling in $a$ and $b$ gives us that $\mathbb{V}ar(X)=((3+d)-(3-d))^2/12=4d^2/12=d^2/12$.

So without knowing $d$ (or alternatively the interval $[a,b]$) we wont have the exact variance.

Intuitively you may understand that the size of the interval matters for the variance. If the interval is very small then there will be low variance, because we have a small deviation from the center. This is larger for bigger intervals and thus is the variance larger.

Comment: +1 nice job making clear what's missing from the question, and guessing what might be meant.